# Difference between binary, String.t, char_list and [char] in a typespec

Tags: elixir, typespec

Which are the different between binary, String.t, char_list, [char] etc when defining a typespec?

```
@spec method(binary) :: binary
```

and

```
@spec method(String.t) :: String.t
```

Are they equivalent? Doc says:

- binary Used for Elixir strings.
- char_list Used for Erlang strings.
  Defined as [char].

Comment: Few hours ago you were provided with a reference https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#t:t/0 `String.t` as clearly stated there is _an alias_ for `binary()`. `[char]` is a completely different thing.

Comment: http://elixir-lang.github.io/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`String.t`  is the same as `binary`, see its definition [here](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/5294a739b47238409c517e07c2c3e1ccd129cfac/lib/elixir/lib/string.ex#L206).

`char_list` is more than a plain list of chars. It's defined in the `unicode` module in Erlang to be:

```
maybe_improper_list(char() | unicode_binary() | charlist(),
                    unicode_binary() | [])
```

So it includes both proper and improper lists and the list can contain chars, binaries, or charlists or the empty list.

Comment: So if binary and String.t are the same, do you know if there is any best practices on which one use String.t or binary for typespec?

Comment: I can't find a reference right now but from what I remember, `String.t` is preferred when you're using it for textual data (UTF-8) and `binary` is preferred for arbitrary data, e.g. network packets, compressed data, etc.

Comment: @Dogbert here is the reference: [Notes](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/typespecs.html#notes), amongst the list of types defined in Elixir. I have never heard of any distinction between `String.t` and `binary()` since the former is an alias for the latter.

Comment: @mudasobwa yeah I meant a reference for when `String.t` is used vs `binary`. I remember reading somewhere about the convention of when to use`String.t` and when to use `binary`. They're identical though like you say so it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Coming across this many years later, but you are right about the preferred convention according to the [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/typespecs.html#the-string-type). tl;dr "Note that String.t() and binary() are equivalent to analysis tools. Although, for those reading the documentation, String.t() implies it is a UTF-8 encoded binary."